# R - How to subset a dataframe by month?

Tags: r, date, subset

Ok so I'm trying to subset this data for the months of June, July and August respectively. I converted the dates to class "Date" by using the as.Date function.

```
BG.data$Date <- as.Date(BG.data$TIMESTAMP, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Next I try to subset the data by selecting the start and end dates in the month of July.

```
July <- selectByDate(BG.data$Date, start = "1/7/2014", end = "31/7/2014")
```

And I keep getting this error message.

```
 Error in as.Date.default(date) : 
 do not know how to convert 'date' to class “Date”
```

Why??!!!? I have what I'm trying to subset in the class Date so I don't know why it won't work!

Comment: You might find the `lubridate` package to be easier than dates in base R.

Comment: Which function within that package?

Comment: I don't know how `selectByDate` works, but your `start` and `end` dates are formated `%d/%m/%Y`, whereas dates of class `Date` are formated `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Checked `selectByDate`. It's in package `openair`. It has a `month` argument: "A month or months to select. Can either be numeric e.g. month = 1:6 to select months 1-6 (January to June), or by name".  Furthermore, you supply a _vector_ as first argument, whereas the help text says that you should give a _data frame_. Please read the help text before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep things simple, try saving the month as a new column and using that:

```
BG.data$month <- factor(format(data.new$timestamp, "%B"),
                       levels = month.name)
```

Then you can use this in for loops:

```
for (month in unique(BG.data$month)){
# get the subset
BG.subset <- BG.data[,BG.data$month == month]
# now do something with that subset
}
```

You can also use it in aggregate:

```
aggregate(something ~ month,
          data = BG.data,
          FUN = function(x){ # custom function })
```

and so-on.

Comment: @NickDriscoll: No worries. if this was useful, could you either up vote (arrow to the left of the answer) or select this as the preferred answer (tick to the left of the answer). That's how I get my warm & fuzzies. Thanks!